# How to rewrite/overwrite strings/lines in a text file?

Tags: c++

I'm totally new in c++ and having problem with a particular portion of my program. As no one to help me in real, I have dared to ask it here. If a text file includes this line "hELp mE", it should be rewritten/overwritten as "HelP Me" in the same exact text file. What i know is that, I might need to use  `ofstream` for the overwriting but i'm very confused about how it should be done. I have tried for about 2 hours and failed. Here is my half completed code which is only able to read from the file.

```
 int main()
 {
   string sentence;
   ifstream firstfile;
   firstfile.open("alu.txt");
   while(getline(firstfile,sentence))
      {  
         cout<<sentence<<endl;
         for(int i=0;sentence[i] !='\0';i++)
           {
             if((sentence[i] >='a' && sentence[i] <='z') || (sentence[i] >='A' && sentence[i] <='Z'))
              {

                 if(isupper(sentence[i]))
                    sentence[i]=tolower(sentence[i]);
                 else if(islower(sentence[i]))
                    sentence[i]=toupper(sentence[i]);
              }
         }
      }


 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why downvoted !! If any admin finds my question inappropriate, Please let me know, I will delete it asap

Comment: You should read each line from the input file in a loop. Examine each line after you've got it to see if it contains your search text (hELp mE). If it does, replace it with your replacement text (HelP Me). Finally, write the line (changed or not) to your output file.

Comment: I think the question is perfectly fine. A downvote without comment is not fair, especially when dealing with a new user who is unable to learn from that action.

Comment: @Sarvin _"Why downvoted"_ Hover your mouse pointer over the downvote button and read the tooltip.

Comment: @xsquared I seriously disagree.

Comment: So, if you think the question is not useful, write down what research effort we expect here, what would have been useful to add etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's works good:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string sentence;
    ifstream firstfile;
    firstfile.open("alu.txt");
    while(getline(firstfile,sentence))
    {
        cout<<sentence<<endl;
        for(int i=0; sentence[i] !='\0'; i++)
        {
            if((sentence[i] >='a' && sentence[i] <='z') || (sentence[i] >='A' && sentence[i] <='Z'))
            {

                if(isupper(sentence[i]))
                    sentence[i]=tolower(sentence[i]);
                else if(islower(sentence[i]))
                    sentence[i]=toupper(sentence[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    firstfile.close();
    cout<<sentence<<endl;
    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open ("alu.txt");
    myfile<<sentence;
    myfile.close();

    return 0;
}
```

according to your code, I simply just `close()` your read mode and open `open()` mode & take the `sentence`

this link is may be help to you [Input/output with files in C++](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/)

Comment: Thank you, i knew what functions were needed, also knew what `close()` is needed to be  used but didn't know how to implement it, I've searched enough, but there are too many implementations which just confuses me as a newbie :-)

Comment: I hope, the person who downvoted it will surely show a specific reason for it. And if it somehow violates the rules, i will delete my post ( as said before ) . Have seen some other questions and answers. According to those, i haven't violated any rule i guess. Thank you again, @S_A :-)

Comment: @Sarvin Well, to clear your doubts, it was me who downvoted both, your question and the accepted answer. Why? The question topic was poorly researched, and merely not better than a _gimme teh codes plz_ question. Same reason I've been downvoting the answer that actually _gave you the code_. This kind of questions is frowned upon at StackOverflow, and such answers are.

Comment: I clearly stated that i'm totally a newbie. I have researched enough before posting it but couldn't understand them. I DID knew what functions were required but as an absolute newbie, couldn't understand the implementation as well as couldn't implement them myself.There are so many versions available in internet that, i got confused. It wasn't  not a "gimme teh codes plz" , rather it was an urge to show the implementation of a MENTIONED SPECIFIC single c++ function. Please, don't discourage the new learners like this. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Follow @πάντα ῥεῖ solution, you could using `ifstream` to read the contents in the specific file, then judge and change UPPER/lower for every character. At the end, using `ofstream` to overwrite the original file.

Wish is helpful.

Comment: He has deleted his answer, i haven't still learnt about the vectors yet, but will start soon. Thank you for commenting :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use fstream to do in-place rewriting in C++. This will replace all lowercase with uppercase and vice-versa, character by character.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <locale>

int main()
{
  std::locale loc;
  std::fstream s("a.txt");
  char next;
  int pos = 0;
  while((next = s.peek()) != EOF) {
    if(islower(next,loc))
      next = toupper(next,loc);
    else if(isupper(next,loc))
      next = tolower(next,loc);
    s.seekp(pos);
    s.write(&next,1);
    pos++;
  }
  return 0;
}
```